# Browser extension to spot "low-reputation" Amazon reviewers

Tags: web-browser, amazon

I am looking for a browser extension (Chrome if possible) to spot "low-reputation" Amazon reviewers. The reputation could be defined in any sensible way, e.g. the number of upvotes they receive on their reviews. The point is to spot users that are more likely to be people paid to write reviews.

Comment: That would  work too.